# Run yarn why for all packages at once

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Normally, I would run `yarn why <package-name>` for every module in my `package.json`. Is there a way to tell `yarn` to run `yarn why` for every package in your project at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear this is impossible... when using the command `yarn why node_modules/*`, yarn outputs the following message:

> Too many arguments, maximum of 1.

This leads me to believe that it is impossible to call `yarn why` on more than one package

Answer (score 0):

As yarn doesn't seem to provide a built-in method of checking why all of the packages are installed, you can just invoke `yarn why` in a for-loop for each of the packages.

This is definitely cumbersome for more than a few packages. Therefore we need an easy way to obtain that list of packages.

You can either use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter the dependencies into a temporary file or just use your text editor of choice and save the `dependency`-portion of `package.json` manually.

Either way, the quotes need to go; so run a search and replace action with the following parameters:

Search: `^.+"(.+?)",$`
Replace: `\1`

Now you can execute `yarn why` in a for-loop over each entry in your temporary file:

```sh
# Print json-array into installed_modules
cat package.json | jq '.dependencies | keys' > installed_modules                                   

# edit / search-replace in file 
[…]  

# Loop through each module and run `yarn why` on it
# This is fish-shell for-loop syntax. 
# You might have to look up how your shell (i.e. bash) does this
for module in (cat installed_modules); 
    yarn why $module;
end
```